# Print table name on which query is executed

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

Looking at the following lines of code:

```
query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table"
cur.execute(query)
conn.commit()
# print(table_name)
```

I'm running the query against multiple tables with various query and I want to return the name of the table and the action executed each time. Is there a way to get some kind of meta data from `cur.execute` or `conn.commit` on the action running?

In the example above I'd like to print the table name (my_table) and the action (DROP TABLE). however I want this to be dynamic. If I'm creating a table I want to the name of the table newly created and the action (CREATE TABLE).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick and Dirty

```py
tables = ['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3']
action = 'DROP TABLE'
for table in tables:
    cur.execute(f'{str(action)} IF EXISTS {str(table)}')
    print(f'ACTION: {action}')
    print(f'TABLE:  {table}')
conn.commit()
```

**HOWEVER**, *please do not ever do something like this in anything other than a tiny app that will never leave your computer, and **especially** not with anything that will accept input from a user*.

[Bad things will happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Dynamically interfacing with databases using OOP is a solved problem, and its not worth reinventing the wheel. Have you considered using an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)?

Comment: my question is exactly about not reinventing the wheel and if it was possible to do something with psycopg2 only. I don't have the possibility for SQLAlchemy in that case. So I guess this is not really possible based on your answer?

Comment: Psycopg2 is more of a driver than an ORM, so its really only giving you the *ability* to communicate.  You can check out the [source](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/tree/master/lib) and see about perhaps expanding on the provided classes, but they're really all just abstractions of the functionality I outlined above.